# Which client to use for AS400 terminal?

Tags: terminal, console, ibm-midrange

I would like to connect to AS400 machine but I do not know which client to use. I have clients installed at work but I do not remember how it is called.

I use Windows 7.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Oh god. Ask your IT guy or the team responsible for admin-ing the i. Or the guy next to you. You're asking us for the name of a piece of software that it already on your computer?

Comment: This might be the very definition of "too localized".

Comment: Please take a few moments to read the FAQ. Server Fault is not for end user questions. OTOH, if you admin has a problem feel free to tell them about us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mochasoft](http://www.mochasoft.dk/) has clients for most platforms. There are open-source alternatives like [TN5250](http://tn5250.sourceforge.net/). Then there is always [IBM i Access](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/software/access/windows/) which is a licensed product from IBM. It is usually purchased with the system and you pay a yearly maintenence.